# CTE Error : Incorrect syntax near comma

Tags: c#, sql, syntax, common-table-expression

Can some one give some lights:

I am getting error near comma:

```
  ;with cteClaims as (
    select a.LoanId, a.ID, a.ClaimType, a.ClaimStatus, a.ClaimTypeDescription                   
      FROM [spd].[claims].[Population] a                    
      group by a.LoanId, a.ID, a.ClaimType, a.ClaimStatus, a.ClaimTypeDescription                   
      having a.ClaimStatus not in ('Closed', 'Denied', 'Paid')                  
      ), ctePopulation as (  
      select a.LoanId, a.ID, a.ClaimType, a.ClaimStatus, a.ClaimTypeDescription                 
      FROM [spd].[claims].[Population] a                    
      join cteClaims b on a.LoanId = b.LoanId                   
      group by a.LoanId, a.ID, a.ClaimType, a.ClaimStatus, a.ClaimTypeDescription)  
       select loanid as cteLoanId 
        from [spd].[claims].[Population] where id in (select id from ctePopulation)
   /// Error is here near this comma  below 
     , cteLoanBase as (
        select 
               a.LoanId as [Loan#]
             , a.AcquisitionDt as [AcquisitionDt]
             , a.CorpRecoverableBalanceAmt as [CorpRecoverableBalanceAmt]
             , a.EscrowBalance as [EscrowBalance]
             , a.FirstPaymentDueDt as [FirstPaymentDueDt]
             , a.InvestorLoanId as [InvestorLoanId]
             , a.InvestorPoolId as [InvestorPoolId]
             , a.LoanStatusId as [LoanStatusId]
```

Comment: What does this have to do with C#? You've only posted SQL, right?

Comment: Which RDBMS is this for? Please add a tag to specify whether you're using `mysql`, `postgresql`, `sql-server`, `oracle` or `db2` - or something else entirely.

Answer (score 0):

You should `select` only after the `cte` definitions are finished. The code has a `select` in between the cte definitions.

```
 ;with cteClaims as (
select a.LoanId, a.ID, a.ClaimType, a.ClaimStatus, a.ClaimTypeDescription                   
  FROM [spd].[claims].[Population] a                    
  group by a.LoanId, a.ID, a.ClaimType, a.ClaimStatus, a.ClaimTypeDescription                   
  having a.ClaimStatus not in ('Closed', 'Denied', 'Paid')                  
  ), ctePopulation as (  
  select a.LoanId, a.ID, a.ClaimType, a.ClaimStatus, a.ClaimTypeDescription                 
  FROM [spd].[claims].[Population] a                    
  join cteClaims b on a.LoanId = b.LoanId                   
  group by a.LoanId, a.ID, a.ClaimType, a.ClaimStatus, a.ClaimTypeDescription)  
 , cteLoanBase as ( ...)

 select loanid as cteLoanId 
 from [spd].[claims].[Population] where id in (select id from ctePopulation)
```

One more thing to mention here: `group by` is being used in the `cte` though no aggregation is being used on any of the columns. This should be avoided.

Comment: can u rewrite the query

Comment: @vkp . . . The `group by` is fine.  It is equivalent to `select distinct`.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps it would help if you better indent your code...

Your code:

```
 ;with 
    cteClaims as (
        SELECT a.LoanId, a.ID, a.ClaimType, a.ClaimStatus, a.ClaimTypeDescription                   
        FROM [spd].[claims].[Population] a                    
            GROUP BY a.LoanId, a.ID, a.ClaimType, a.ClaimStatus, a.ClaimTypeDescription                   
              HAVING a.ClaimStatus not in ('Closed', 'Denied', 'Paid')),
    ctePopulation as (  
        SELECT a.LoanId, a.ID, a.ClaimType, a.ClaimStatus, a.ClaimTypeDescription                 
        FROM [spd].[claims].[Population] a                    
        JOIN cteClaims b on a.LoanId = b.LoanId                   
        GROUP BY a.LoanId, a.ID, a.ClaimType, a.ClaimStatus, a.ClaimTypeDescription)  

    SELECT loanid as cteLoanId 
        FROM [spd].[claims].[Population] 
    WHERE id in (select id from ctePopulation)

   /// Error is here near this comma  below 


     , cteLoanBase as (
        select 
               a.LoanId as [Loan#]
             , a.AcquisitionDt as [AcquisitionDt]
             , a.CorpRecoverableBalanceAmt as [CorpRecoverableBalanceAmt]
             , a.EscrowBalance as [EscrowBalance]
             , a.FirstPaymentDueDt as [FirstPaymentDueDt]
             , a.InvestorLoanId as [InvestorLoanId]
             , a.InvestorPoolId as [InvestorPoolId]
             , a.LoanStatusId as [LoanStatusId]
```

My guess:

```
 ;with 
    cteClaims as (
        SELECT a.LoanId, a.ID, a.ClaimType, a.ClaimStatus, a.ClaimTypeDescription                   
        FROM [spd].[claims].[Population] a                    
            GROUP BY a.LoanId, a.ID, a.ClaimType, a.ClaimStatus, a.ClaimTypeDescription                   
              HAVING a.ClaimStatus not in ('Closed', 'Denied', 'Paid')),
    ctePopulation as (  
        SELECT a.LoanId, a.ID, a.ClaimType, a.ClaimStatus, a.ClaimTypeDescription                 
        FROM [spd].[claims].[Population] a                    
        JOIN cteClaims b on a.LoanId = b.LoanId                   
        GROUP BY a.LoanId, a.ID, a.ClaimType, a.ClaimStatus, a.ClaimTypeDescription),
    cteLoanBase as (
        SELECT 
                   a.LoanId as [Loan#]
                 , a.AcquisitionDt as [AcquisitionDt]
                 , a.CorpRecoverableBalanceAmt as [CorpRecoverableBalanceAmt]
                 , a.EscrowBalance as [EscrowBalance]
                 , a.FirstPaymentDueDt as [FirstPaymentDueDt]
                 , a.InvestorLoanId as [InvestorLoanId]
                 , a.InvestorPoolId as [InvestorPoolId]
                 , a.LoanStatusId as [LoanStatusId]
    FROM ???  )


    SELECT loanid as cteLoanId 
        FROM [spd].[claims].[Population] 
    WHERE id in (select id from ctePopulation)
```

It's hard to guess what you want...

- You are missing a parenthesis at the end.
- You should define your "With" Clause before the main select you are doing (cteLoadBase is defined after your main select).
- You are missing a FROM